# Is there a relatively easy way to add the "Cone of Influence" to a waveletscalogram?

Tags: plotting, wavelet-analysis

I am analyzing time series data using the [`ContinousWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContinousWaveletTransform.html) function and plotting the results with [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html). I would like to plot the cone of influence on top of the [`WaveletScalogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WaveletScalogram.html) plot. Is there a relatively simple and general way to calculate and plot the cone of influence? (note - using the default [`MexicanHatWavelet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MexicanHatWavelet.html))